# c++ map contaiter under multithread - iterator->seconds change under read mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is changing address of pointer always atomic operation? is it safe to change pointer = NULL to some value(address) under multithread application?

**more info:** 
There is `std::map<int, SomePointer*`. I access `map` with `find()` with locked `mutex` for `READING`. I get `iterator` to some element and then I want to change `iterator->second` (in another words `SomePointer*`)

So, while mutex of `map` locked for reading, `map` will not changed at this time. Only other readers will have access to the `map`. So, for me it's fine if other readers will get old value `NULL` or `NEW ADDRESS`... but, of course, I fear that some thread will access to some `average state` and get corrupted address. So, is it safe to change `iterator->second` under `read mutex`?

Comment: What is a map _contaiter_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, changing the value of anything that isn't explicitly made thread safe is not thread safe.

If you wish to perform possibly-concurrent writes and reads to/from a pointer without a data race or a lock, use a [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Comment: i'm under c++99. I can change read mutex to write mutex, but this would slow down the program :(

Comment: There is no C++99, only C++98.  If this is the case, you may be able to get platform-specific atomics.  For example, on Windows use [InterlockedExchangePointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683609(v=vs.85\).aspx).

Comment: Perhaps you can use [GCC's atomic built-ins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html)?